# Magento Database dump restore not working

Tags: database, magento-1

I have got a dump of my live Magento database: it is 11GB in size and when I go to restore it, it does not do anyhting.

[image]

Shows these variables being set then says dump completed but no tables are actually being created, why is this ?

Comment: Are you restoring to a different database name? How do you restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really am an idiot at times:

It is mysql to restore not mysqldump!!!!! was using invalid syntax:

correct one is:

```
mysql -u --USERNAME-- -p DB_Name < backup.sql
```